# React JS onKeyUp event does not sending data to function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, fetch, dom-events

Im trying to create an `ajax user search` like linkedin's, so when i type a character from the keyboard i should get results without pressing the enter key.

In my input field i have the **onKeyUp={sendData(this)}** to send the data in the sendData function, and then fetch the results.

```
<input type="text" id="userfield" onKeyUp={sendData(this)}/>
```

```
 function sendData (input){
    if (input!=null){
    console.log("data:",input)
    fetch('/userSearch',{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({ input: input.value})
    
    })
    }
  }
```

My problem is that in the `console.log("data:",input)` line i get undefined. Which means the onKeyUp event sends nothing to the function. Im i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React `onKeyUp` and event listeners in general expect a function to be passed, and will pass the `event` as an argument by default. In your case you want to pass the `sendData` function like so:

```
<input type="text" id="userfield" onKeyUp={sendData}/>
```

and then receive the input element like:

```js
function sendData (event){
   const input = event.target;
   // Do stuff with input
  }
```

Also if you are trying to fetch some data you have to handle it somehow. You should either add a `.then((result)=>{/* Handle the result */})` to the `fetch` call or make `sendData` an `async` function and then `await` the result like:

```js
async function sendData (event){
   const input = event.target;
   const result = await fetch(/*...*/)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use

```
   <input type="text" id="userfield" onKeyUp={(e)=>sendData(e.target.value)}/>
```

**e.target** gives you the element that triggered the event.

**e.target.value** retrieves the value of that element